# signal handler and multithreading

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, signals

I know that signal is a way of communication between CPU and OS kernel. A signal can interrupt the sequence of instructions, execute the handler and go back to the sequence of instructions.

Here is a piece of description of this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-reent/index.html):

> When a signal that is being caught is handled by a process, the normal
>   sequence of instructions being executed by the process is temporarily
>   interrupted by the signal handler. The process then continues
>   executing, but the instructions in the signal handler are now
>   executed. If the signal handler returns, the process continues
>   executing the normal sequence of instructions it was executing when
>   the signal was caught.

Here is my test:

```
void func(int p)
{
    cout<<"int"<<endl;
    sleep(5);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, func);
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"main"<<endl;
        sleep(2);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I execute it and if I press `ctrl+C`, `int` will be printed and then I have to wait for 5 seconds, no matter how many times `ctrl+C` I pressed while waiting for the 5 seconds, nothing happened.

Then I make another test:

```
void func(int p)
{
    cout<<"int"<<endl;
    sleep(5);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, func);
    thread t1([](){while(1){cout<<"t1"<<endl; sleep(2);}});
    thread t2([](){while(1){cout<<"t2"<<endl; sleep(2);}});
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

For this code, I found that I could press `ctrl+C` three times continually and three `int` would be printed, then I have to wait for about 5 seconds.

So it seems that the first `ctrl+C` interrupts the `t1` thread, the second interrupts the `t2` thread and the third interrupts the main thread.

So signal only interrupt thread instead of the whole process if there are multi-threading?

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior.  Per [footnote 183 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX allows the calling of async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).  Using `cout` and calling `sleep()` are not async-signal-safe.

Comment: You don't want to have to handle signals that way. Not ever.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Yes, you are right. But I need to print something to debug, so I think I have no choice. Using non-reentrant functions in signal handler can be undefined behavior. At least for the code above, it works as expected.

Comment: @Yves On a POSIX system: `write( STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, strlen( buffer ) );`  Or `STDERR_FILENO`, if you prefer.  Build a C-style string, then use `write()`.

Comment: On Linux specifically, you might consider [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). However, it does have shortcomings (STFW)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**INTRODUCTION**

First of all each thread has its own mask that specifies which signals it is listening to. When a thread is created it inherits the mask of the thread that is creating it (let me call it the *parent thread)* that is active when `pthread_create` is called.

Generally it is better that if a thread is listening to a signal then the others should not, unless you want to have many threads that do the same stuff (for example when processing a connection request in a server to process many requests simultaneously). In this way you always know which thread function is processing the signal. Otherwise you do not have any idea which thread function is executing given the signal, making it impossible to debug (an example is your own question).

To **change the mask** of the *child thread* that is being created from the *parent thread* you create a new mask, you set it active, create a new thread with `pthread_create` and then in the *parent thread* set the previous mask active again (see the code at the end of the answer).

**EDIT**: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal) it is better to use `sigaction()` instead of `signal`. In modern systems `signal()` is implemented with `sigaction()` so there should not be any difference. However if its old implementation is used, problems might arise.

**ANSWER**

> So signal only interrupt thread instead of the whole process if there
> are multi-threading?

**NO**: Signals are just signals, they do not do anything. Actions associated to signals have the power to do stuff, including stopping the program or terminating the thread. Each signal has a default action associated and the default action for `SIGINT` is to interrupt the process.

With you handler you are overwriting the default action. So it will not stop the program anymore but it will do what you have specified in the thread function.

In the first case you have only one thread, the main one, which is an infinite loop, it always catches the signal as long as he is alive so that's why the behavior. If you resend the signal, the signal is momentarily blocked until the signal handler ends the execution. Nevertheless if many signals are sent while the handler is executing, you can loose some signals.
In fact as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442102/what-happens-when-a-signal-is-received-while-already-in-a-signal-handler), blocked signals are set to pending, but not queued. The term *pending* means that the operating system remembers that there is a signal waiting to be delivered at the next opportunity by setting a flag, and *not queued* means that it does this by setting a flag somewhere, but not by keeping an exact record of how many signals have arrived.
So if the signals is sent once, 5 times or more (try to press CTRL+C more times with your program: I have tried) while the signal handler is executing it produces the exactly same behaviour.

In your second case you have 3 threads: the `main` one, `t1`, and `t2`: all of them are enabled to see the signal `SIGINT` and all of them have associated the same signal handler. If you press 3 times one after the other all three of them will execute the handler: that is why you don't see any delay. If you press very very fast though and more than 3 times (the number of threads listening to that signal) I think you will see something similar to the first behaviour.

I will end my answer with [the code I posted in a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612546/how-to-terminate-threads-cleanly-in-c) where I was setting masks so that some signals were caught only by the main thread:

```
int main()
{
    int err;
    sigset_t omask, mask;
    pthread_t thread_motionSensor;
    pthread_t thread_tempReading;
    pthread_t thread_platformPost;

    printf("Created threads IDs\n");

    ...
    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler)==SIG_ERR)
        printf("Error on recording SIGINT HANDLER\n");

    /*Create a new mask to block all signals for the following thread*/
    sigfillset(&mask);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, &omask);
    printf("Trying to create threads\n");
    if ((err = pthread_create (&thread_motionSensor, NULL, task1, NULL))!=0)
    {
    printf("Thread 1 not created: error %d\n", err);
        err_exit((const char)err, "pthread_create error");
    }
    printf("Thread 1 created. Trying to create Thread 2\n");
    if((err = pthread_create (&thread_tempReading,   NULL, task2, NULL))!=0)
    {
    printf("Thread 2 not created: error %d\n", err);
        err_exit((const char)err, "pthread_create error");
    }
    printf("Thread 2 created. Trying to create Thread 3\n");
    if ((err = pthread_create (&thread_platformPost, NULL, task3, NULL))!=0)
    {
     printf("Thread 3 not created: error %d %d\n", err);
         err_exit((const char)err, "pthread_create error");
    }
    printf("Thread 3 created\n");
    /*The main thread must block the SIGALRM but catch SIGINT
    SIGQUIT, SIGTERM, SIgkILL*/
    /*empty the omask set from all signals */
    sigemptyset(&omask);
    /*add the signals to the omask*/
    sigaddset(&omask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&omask, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&omask, SIGKILL);
    sigaddset(&omask, SIGTERM);
    /*unblock all signals in omask*/
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &omask, NULL);
    printf("Main thread waiting for signal\n");
    /*pause will stop the main thread until any signal not blocked by omask will be received*/
    pause();
    printf("Exit signal received: cancelling threads\n");

    pthread_cancel(thread_motionSensor);
    pthread_cancel(thread_tempReading);
    pthread_cancel(thread_platformPost);
    pthread_join(thread_motionSensor, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_tempReading,  NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_platformPost, NULL);
    printf("Exiting from main thread and process\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: +1 on your answer. Here's a couple ideas for improvements: mentioning the async-signal-safe [`getpid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) or [`pthread_self`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) functions to get idea of thread handler is being invoked for; mentioning how Ctrl-C is typically handled by a shell, process groups, and the [`kill(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) function with negative PIDs.

Comment: Thanks... I will check them and see if I can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how many threads the process has, some thread catches the signal and runs the signal handler while the other threads (if any) go on about their business. The signal is sent to the process, but what the process does when it gets the signal is dependent on how the process, and the threads in, configured its signal handlers.

The full rules are quite complicated and I think it's safe to say that very few programmers bother to full understand them and generally avoid signals except for very limited purposes. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h033a/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> So signal only interrupt thread instead of the whole process if there are multi-threading?

Yes. A signal interrupts a single thread of execution. At least according to the POSIX standard. C standard itself doesn't specify behaviour of processes or threads.

If a signal is generated for a multi threaded process as opposed to being generated for particular thread, the signal will be delivered to exactly one of the threads belonging to that process (unless the signal is blocked by all threads).